# Autoboot LG Android Phone

Tags: boot

How can i setup my LG Sprint Phone Model LGLS885 to auto-boot when plugged in. there is instruction on the web to modify the lpm file, but there is no lpm file in system/bin.

Answer (score 0):

look for possible file, like charger_monitor (some lg systems use it) or any file contains the word "charge" or "lpm". change it's name and try to turn off the phone and charge it. if there is not an usual battery animation - that's the file!

if it's not the file, don't forget to rename it.